# template of template without default constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a template class that doesn't have default constructor.
For `A<int>` works fine, but for `A<A<int>>` I don't know how to get it to work.

```
  1   #include <iostream>
  2   using namespace std;
  3 
  4   template <typename T>
  5   class A {
  6     T x;
  7 
  8    public:
  9     A(T y) { x = y; }
 10   };
 11 
 12   int main() {
 13     A<int> a(0);
 14     A<A<int> > b(A<int>(0));
 15 
 16     return 0;
 17   }
```

Error list from clang

```
    test.cpp:9:5: error: constructor for 'A<A<int> >' must explicitly initialize the member 'x' which does not have a default constructor
        A(T y) { x = y; }
        ^
    test.cpp:14:16: note: in instantiation of member function 'A<A<int> >::A' requested here
        A<A<int> > b(A<int>(0));
                   ^
    test.cpp:6:7: note: member is declared here
        T x;
          ^
    test.cpp:5:9: note: 'A<int>' declared here
      class A {
            ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not properly constructing `x` in the initializer list of the constructor, hence `A(T y)` must default construct `x` before invoking `operator=` to copy assign `y` to it.

`int` provides a default constructor, which just let the value uninitialized, but `A<int>` does not.

Your constructor should be

```
A(T y) : x(y) { }
```